# how to adjust div width based on other div postion

Tags: javascript, css, width, jquery-draggable

I have two div's one is `div-content`(red color) and second is `div-content2`(yellow color).`div-content` size is 0 to 50% and `div-content2` size 50% to 100%.

Now In my screen 50% `div-content` and 50% `div-content2`

I need `div-content1` drag left to right `div-content1` width is 70 .In that time `div-content2` will be 30.if `div-content2` drag right to left width is 65 , in that time  `div-content` width 35

finely when increases and content remain content will auto adjust So Please give me any Idea.

I am now to Stackoverflow .if i wrong to write Please guided me .

Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just the concept of it:

```js
    
    var drag = false,
    maxW = $('.wrap').width();
    $('.div1').click(function(){}).mousedown(function(event){
      drag = true;  
    });

$(document).mousemove(function(event){
    if(drag) {
        if($('.div1').width() < maxW) {
            $('.div1').width(event.pageX); 
        }
    }
}).mouseup(function(){
    drag = false;
});
```

```css
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
    width:50%;
    height:300px;
}

.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    width: 50%;
    background-color:red;
    cursor:e-resize;
}

.div1:focus {
    cursor:e-resize;
}

.div2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but red and yellow div's are moveing like move over but i need drag Please help me

Comment: Please give me any idea about moveDrag

Comment: ok i updated my answer. You just do the rest of the the limits :P

Comment: thanks jest small need only edges curse will me changed remaining it's will me showing like normal but above code will to total curse showing different